# React native tabBarButton and tabBarIcon

Tags: react-native

What is the purpose and usage of tabBarButton and tabBarIcon? I've seen examples where there was a declaration of tabBarButton and tabBarIcon at Tab.Screen at the same time. From what I understand it's a redundant thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

The docs that explain the difference between tabBarButton and tabBarIcon can be found [here](https://%20https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator).

To summarize what they say, `tabBarButton` is a function that returns a **React element** as the tab bar button. It wraps the icon and label, and renders `Pressable` by default. You can specify custom implementations with `tabBarButton`.
An example of this would look like the following:

```js
 tabBarButton: (props) => (
     <TouchableOpacity
       {...props}
        style={props.style}>

          <MaterialCommunityIcons name={'home'} color={'grey'} size={25} />
           <Text> Home </Text>

     </TouchableOpacity>
              ),
```

`tabBarIcon` is a function that can be given `{ focused: boolean, color: string, size: number }` and returns a **React node** to display in the tab bar.
An example of this would look like the following:

```js
tabBarIcon: ({color,size}) => (
    <MaterialCommunityIcons name="cog" color={color} size={size} />
  ),
```

I haven't found extensive documentation about either of these options, but from working with both of them at different times, I *believe* that `tabBarButton` allows for a wider range of customization.